# How do I write a 2D-array parameter specification in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

### Context

I'm not used to parameter specifications when declaring a function in python.

In the following example, we specify the parameters `x` and `y` to be of type `int`:

```py
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y
```

I'm using numpy to initialize a 2D array of 0s and I'm not sure how to specify a 2D array as my parameter. Here's what I have:

```py
import numpy as np

def fillWithOnes(array: type([[]])) -> None:
    for row in array:
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            row[i] = 1

table = np.zeros((5,5))

fillWithOnes(table)

print (table)
```

### Question

Is `type([[]])` on line 3 correct? I've been having trouble finding an answer in python's Typing docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

I also noticed that I can specify the parameter, `array` to be an `int` and the code still works. Which leads me to my second question: Is typing purely for third party tools; maybe general sanity and readability as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.zeros` returns a `ndarray`:

```
>>> type(np.zeros((5,5)))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So that's what you'd annotate it as:

```
def fillWithOnes(array: np.ndarray) -> None:
    . . .
```

If you wanted to be general though, you could annotate it as a Protocol/base class to allow for multiple different types. You currently only need an "iterable of sequences of ints", so you can specify that:

```
from typing import Sequence, Iterable

def fillWithOnes(array: Iterable[Sequence[int]]) -> None:
    pass
```

Now it can accepts lists, `ndarray`s, and even types you define.

---

I'll just mention, for lists, `type([[]])` works, slightly. It disregards the inner type of the list. It would be equivalent to:

```
def fillWithOnes(array: list) -> None:
    . . .
```

It specifies that it's a list, but doesn't say anything about the element type.

Currently, you need to use a `List` wrapper:

```
from typing import List

def fillWithOnes(array: List[List[int]]) -> None:  # I'm assuming the cells are ints
    . . .
```

---

Answer (score 0):

What about following?

```
from typeing import (NoReturn)
from nptyping import (NDArray, Shape, Int32)


def fill_with_ones(array: NDArray[Shape["*, *"], Int32) -> NoReturn:
    ...
```